# Python how to pick 3rd occurence in nested json array

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am working with one of my requirement

My requirement: I need to pick and print only 3rd "id" from "syrap" list from the nested json file. I am not getting desired output. Any help will be appreciated.

*Test file*:

```
{
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters":
        {   "process": "abc",
                    "mix": "0303",
            "syrap":
                [
                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                    { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                ]
        },
        "rate": 0.55,
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
            { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
            { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
            { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
        ]
}
```

*Expected output in a csv:*

```
0001,donut,abc,0303,1003
```

*My code:*

```py
import requests
import json
import csv

f = open('testdata.json')
data = json.load(f)
f.close()

f = csv.writer(open('testout.csv', 'wb+'))

for item in data:
    f.writerow([item['id'], item[type], item['batters'][0]['process'], 
                item['batters'][0]['mix'], 
                item['batters'][0]['syrap'][0]['id'], 
                item['batters'][0]['syrap'][1]['id'], 
                item['batters'][0]['syrap'][2]['id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code showing how you can iterate through json content parsed as a dictionary:

```
import json

json_str = '''{
"id": "0001",
"type": "donut",
"name": "Cake",
"ppu": 0.55,
"batters":
    {   "process": "abc",
                "mix": "0303",
        "syrap":
            [
                { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
            ]
    },
    "rate": 0.55,
"topping":
    [
        { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
        { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
        { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
        { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
        { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
        { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
        { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
    ]
}
'''

jsondict = json.loads(json_str)

syrap_node = jsondict['batters']['syrap']

for item in syrap_node:
     print (f'id:{item["id"]} type: {item["type"]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, `data[“batters”][“syrap”][2][“id”]`

Much better way to achieve this would be

```
f = open('testout.csv', 'wb+')
with f:
    fnames = ['id','type','process','mix','syrap']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fnames)    
    writer.writeheader()

    for item in data:
        print item
        writer.writerow({'id' : item['id'], 'type': item['type'], 
                         'process' : item['batters']['process'],
                         'mix': item['batters']['mix'],
                         'syrap': item['batters']['syrap'][2]['id']})
```

You need to make sure that data is actually a list. if it is not a list, don't use for loop.
simply,

```
writer.writerow({'id' : data['id'], 'type': data['type'], 
                         'process' : data['batters']['process'],
                         'mix': data['batters']['mix'],
                         'syrap': data['batters']['syrap'][2]['id']})
```

Comment: This is not working data[“batters”][“syrap”][2][“id”]. i am seeing this error "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"

Comment: please post your code as code, not picture, will try to run it,

Comment: @raj, the issue you have is that your data is not a list[]. it is a dictionary{}